# .project file missing, but project opens fine on my mac, but not lecturers home PC

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, project

bit of a beginner to all this. But this year we have been asked to make a Android Tic Tac Toe game, and I've just finished it, but sent it off to my lecturer to check out a simple problem I was having.

However he says he cannot open it as it is not recognised as a project and it is missing the .project file.

When looking back over my old projects, not a single one of them has a .project file in it (a least 30 project), however they all open absolutely fine on my Mac, and the PC's in uni when I copy them onto my USB and import them into Eclipse.

The deadline is monday and I'm getting a bit worried. I don't mind making a new project from scratch and copying my code into it. But I don't see how it will help seeing as none of my previous projects have been made with them.

Any help will be GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks, Will

Comment: Did you send the `.project` file _and_ the `.classpath` file?

Comment: They don't appear to exist in the project folder.... although the project imports and opens just fine on my computer.

Comment: The point is, Eclipse is _completely_ run via plugins. Basically everything you can see and do is done via a plugin, so it's just a matter of finding out what's different (missing) between the two. Just for [reference](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2FresInt_filesystem.htm).

Comment: For an Android project, import should work without a project file but your lecturer may simply be trying to open the project (which doesn't exist because you didn't send it). Are you *sure* the `.project` and `.classpath` files don't exist? If you're on a Mac, Finder doesn't see them. Use Terminal, navigate to your project directory and do `ls -a` to check.

Comment: As the answers say Mac Finder does not show files starting with `.` so the .project (and .classpath) are there. If you select the project folder (rather than the files in the folder) and copy that it should include all the files in the project including the hidden ones.

Answer (score 1):

A piece of information you may be missing is that files prefixed with a period (`.`) are hidden files on Unix-based OS's. Therefore you will not see them by default in Finder on OSX.

If you open a Terminal, navigate to your project (`cd <project-path>`) and execute `ls -la`, they will show up.

Example output:

```
Justins-iMac:HelloWorld justinjasmann$ ls -la
total 144
drwxr-xr-x  14 justinjasmann  staff    476 26 Feb 16:50 .
drwxrwxrwx  10 justinjasmann  staff    340 28 Feb 01:12 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 justinjasmann  staff    466 26 Feb 16:51 .classpath
-rw-r--r--   1 justinjasmann  staff    813 26 Feb 16:50 .project
-rw-r--r--   1 justinjasmann  staff    845 26 Feb 16:50 AndroidManifest.xml
drwxr-xr-x   2 justinjasmann  staff     68 26 Feb 16:50 assets
drwxr-xr-x  10 justinjasmann  staff    340 28 Feb 01:07 bin
drwxr-xr-x   3 justinjasmann  staff    102 26 Feb 16:51 gen
-rw-r--r--   1 justinjasmann  staff  51394 26 Feb 16:50 ic_launcher-web.png
drwxr-xr-x   3 justinjasmann  staff    102 26 Feb 16:50 libs
-rw-r--r--   1 justinjasmann  staff    781 26 Feb 16:50 proguard-project.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 justinjasmann  staff    563 26 Feb 16:50 project.properties
drwxr-xr-x  14 justinjasmann  staff    476 26 Feb 16:50 res
drwxr-xr-x   3 justinjasmann  staff    102 26 Feb 16:50 src
```

Answer (score 0):

Files who's names begin with '.' are Filtered by default in most views. If your project is working fine, you must have a .project file.