# .metadata folder missing on Mac showing up fine on PC

Tags: macos, database-metadata

I went to an id tech camp recently and they gave us a USB with all our work but it was on a PC so I was trying to get it on my Mac and then it says file not found so I check the folders the .metadata is not there so I use my dad's PC and it's there. Is there a way I can get it on my mac.i need my .project file to open it but it is not showing up on my Mac is there any other besides getting a PC please I would really appreciate it

Comment: possible duplicate of [.project file missing, but project opens fine on my mac, but not lecturers home PC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22107874/project-file-missing-but-project-opens-fine-on-my-mac-but-not-lecturers-home)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Files that start with a dot are hidden on Unix/Linux filesystems so, by default, they don't show up in the Finder.

To make them visible, start the Terminal and type the following and hit `Enter` after each line.

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
killall Finder
```

You can then rename the folder without a dot so it is visible. If you want to hide the dot-files again (i.e. undo the above operation) just change the `YES` to `No` and run the commands again.

Comment: wait I have a question I used eclipse and it was not found when I do this will it work

Comment: If eclipse expects the folder to be called `.metadata` it obviously will not find it if you change its name so that the Finder sees it. I would make it visible like I showed you, then copy and paste the folder so you can see the files in the copy like you want to, then rename the original back how it was so that eclipse is happy.

Comment: I made two folders with dot and without but now it is not finding the project

Comment: I am really sry I u r getting annoyed

Comment: You'll probably have to stop and restart eclipse if you have been making changes.

Comment: Ok now it's finding the project but not the files inside the project wow this thing is getting hard

Comment: Ok now it says 'Open Project' has encountered a problem.

Comment: The project description file (.project) for 'Project3' is missing. This file contains important info about the project. The project will not function properly until this file is restored